# Scatter Plot Error:scatter() got multiple values for argument 'c'

Tags: python, matplotlib

so Im trying to make some code for iris dataset and use KMeans to it.Everything is good but it looks like my code for centroid have some problem that ended up with this error:

```
  plt.scatter(*centroid, c="blue")

    TypeError: scatter() got multiple values for argument 'c'
```

This is my code

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn import metrics
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

direktori = 'iris.data.csv'

names = ['sepal-length','sepal-width','petal-length','petal-width','class']

dataset = pd.read_csv(direktori, names=names)


#ambil variabel untuk cluster
df  = np.array(dataset[['sepal-length','sepal-width','petal-length','petal-width']])
kelas = np.array(dataset['class'])

print('\n')

for i in range (2,8):

    kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=i)
    kmeans.fit(df)

    label = kmeans.labels_
    #evalauasi menggunakan FMI Index
    #ambil label asli dari data
    label_asli = kelas
    label_prediksi = label
    FMI = metrics.fowlkes_mallows_score(label_asli, label_prediksi)
    print("FMI values with n_clusters = ", i, "= ", FMI)   

print('\n')

for i in range (2,8):  
    kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=i)
    kmeans.fit(df)
    centroids= kmeans.cluster_centers_

    label = kmeans.labels_
    labels= kmeans.predict(df)  
    CHIndex = metrics.calinski_harabasz_score(df, label)
    print("CH index with n_clusters = ", i, " = ", CHIndex)

    #menggunakan sepal-length dan sepal-width sebagai bahan untuk visualisasi   
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5,5))

    plt.scatter(df[:, 0], df[:, 1], c=labels, alpha=0.5, edgecolor='k', cmap="viridis")

    #Scatter fuction that caused the error
    for idx, centroid in enumerate(centroids):
        plt.scatter(*centroid, c="blue")

    plt.xlim(0, 8.5)
    plt.ylim(0, 8.5)
    plt.title('Kmeans Visualization for n_clusters = %i' %i)
    plt.xlabel('sepal-length')
    plt.ylabel('sepal-width')

    plt.show()
```

is there a part that I should fix? please give me a detail on which part that I should change with the new line of code.

Comment: Try `plt.scatter(centroid[0], centroid[1] c="blue")` because `*centroid` probably gets converted to 3 values (x,y,z) and that z already sets the `c=` parameter.

Comment: It works, thank you